# что делать если мое сложения в js не работает а оно просто делает 2222 при сложении 22+22=2222 а е 44

Tags: javascript

что делать? если идет не сложения а просто слепливает все вместе в js 22+22=2222 f yt 44

```
let number1 = prompt("введите первое число")
let number2 = prompt("введите первое число")
let sum = number1 + number2
document.getElementById("result").textContent = number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + sum
```

Comment: let number1 = prompt("введите первое число")
              let number2 = prompt("введите первое число")
              let sum = number1 + number2
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + sum

Comment: приводить строку к числу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что prompt считывает строку, нужно явное приведение к типу Number.

```js
let number1 = prompt("введите первое число")
let number2 = prompt("введите первое число")
let sum = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Или `let number1 = +prompt("введите первое число")` — и он сразу будет числом)

Comment: спасибо бро помогло

Answer (score 1):

Используй унарный плюс для приведения к числу.

```
let number1 = +prompt("введите первое число")
let number2 = +prompt("введите первое число")
```

Comment: спасибо помогло прям респект